# Difference between quasi-bialgebra and bialgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Difference between quasi-bialgebra and bialgebra ?

Page 285 of Christian Kassel's Quantum Groups:

Let $A=(A,\Delta,\epsilon)$ be an algebra with comultiplication and counit as above. It is a bialgebra if and only if the category $A$-Mod equipped with the associativity and left/right unit constraints from $Vect(k)$ and action on tensor product of modules defined by $a(u \otimes v) = \Delta(a)(u \otimes v)$ is a tensor category.

Then on Page 368, it says:

Let $A=(A,\Delta,\epsilon)$ be an algebra with comultiplication and counit. It is a quasi-bialgebra if the category $A$-mod equipped with the tensor product of $Vect(k)$ is a tensor category

---

So... it seems like every quasi-bialgebra is a bialgebra to me.. What am i missing here?

Comment: I don't have the book, but in the case of a quasi-bialgebra the category $A$-mod will have a non-trivial associativity constraint (the natural iso $(U\otimes V)\otimes W\to U\otimes (V\otimes W)$), not the usual one in $Vect(k)$

Comment: Ah, okay okay. So it may not be a strict tensor category?